# New user creation in linux

Tags: linux

Can anyone explain what exactly happens when new user is created in linux. I mean how user space is created and everything that happens internally.

what is shell space
From where home space is given etc.

Comment: There is perfect documentation available for you on this @http://www.tldp.org/LDP/sag/html/adduser.html

Answer (score 2):

The only *really* necessary thing is a new entry in the file `/etc/passwd`.  That represents the list of users.

But, typically, however, there will be done some more things.

1. A home directory for the user is created.  This is just a `mkdir` on a path like `/home/bilbo` for the user `bilbo`.  It typically matches the user's name but it does not need to.  Which belongs to which is specified in the `/etc/passwd`.
2. The user's encrypted password is added to /etc/shadow
3. Some files are copied from templates to that new user's home directory.  This depends on the distribution you are using, but often some standard configuration things are done within that new home directory; e. g. creating directories like `/home/bilbo/Pictures` etc.
4. Sometimes also a *group* is created for that user, if so, then typically, that group also is named like the user.  Creating a group is done by inserting an entry to the file `/etc/group`.

On a modern system like Ubuntu the whole user directory might be set up to be mounted from an encrypted path, but this is a special case worth a new question ;-)